# Manipulating silverlight media element and associating with jQuery UI Widget

Tags: silverlight

I have no background with ASP and Silverlight. As a jQuery UI widget developer, I have to write a seekbar widget for silverlight media element player. I need to understand how should I define an interface for my widget if I have to associate it with silverlight?

How can I intercept MediaElement instance?
How can I know what is total media duration?
How can I know about current media position?
How can I call the player to play from some specific position?
How can I bind events with silverlight player so that with each tick it should invoke my seekbar to get updated?

All I want with JS/jQuery environment. What is the best source to start?

NOTE: I am from linux background, so I have moonlight for my browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the [JavaScript API for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903928%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) reference on MSDN. It will provide answers to all of your questions.